# Concrete5.7.5.2 SSL/HTTPS - Invalid form token. Please reload this form and submit again

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, concrete5-5.7

I want to force SSL for my site. It works with putting these 2 lines into .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But when I try to login, it gives me this error:

Invalid form token. Please reload this form and submit again.

Without those lines in .htaccess, it works fine, but SSL is not forced.

Is there any other way to force SSL and to be able to log in?

Thank you.

[SOLVED]
I've changed '[R,L]' to '[R=301,L]', logged out - and now SSL works!

1. My .htaccess:

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
2. Canonical URL is empty
3. URS by SSL is 'https://example.com'
4. Show only canonical URLs is ticked

Comment: Do you have a link where we can test it?
We are using the same style, but it is working for us

Comment: Nicolai, sorry, a link to site, to login or to where? I had to comment out those 2 lines in .htaccess because I couldn't log in anymore

Comment: We are using
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
Try that, who knows. Maybe it works...

Comment: Nevermind! I think I got it. Under `System & Settings`->`SEO & Statistics`->`URLs and Redirection`, have you entered Canonical URLs?

Comment: Yes, I've tried canonical URLs, but it always takes me to an HTTP site. My canonical URL is set to HTTP (http://example.com), my SSL URL is set to HTTPS (https://example.com) and show only by canonical URLs is ticked. I tried setting an HTTP URL to https, but it gives me an error: "The canonical URL provided must start with "http://"." When I leave the HTTP URL blank, it still takes me to a non-SSL site.

Comment: I tried your rewrite rules, it gives me an error: "The page isn't redirecting properly" - site inaccessable

Comment: Now I've gone back to my previous .htaccess, but now it starts taking me to an https site even though I've removed all rewrite rules. So it takes me to an https root, but all other pages are not https. ???

Comment: I've logged out, logged in - and now it's back to http. I've got no idea what's going on

Comment: I got it fixed for us by leaving the canonical HTTP empty, and ONLY fill in the HTTPS.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've updated my question. It fixed itself.

Comment: Thanks @linuxoid, this saved my day!